# I have written a proof for the chain rule, but I am unsure that some of the steps are justified.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, proof-writing

While the proof below gives the correct solution, I am uncertain of its validity, in particular:

If we are allowed go from $\Delta x$ to $\Delta g$ in this section:
$$\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\Delta x=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{\Delta g}{g'(x)}\implies\lim_{\Delta g\to0}\Delta x=\lim_{\Delta g\to0}\frac{\Delta g}{g'(x)}$$

If we are allowed to "plug in" $\Delta x=\frac{\Delta g}{g'(x)}$:
$$\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{f(g(x+\Delta x))-f(g(x))}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta g\to0}\frac{f(g(x)+\Delta g)-f(g(x))}{\frac{\Delta g}{g'(x)}}$$

Another problem is that dividing by $g'(x)$ could result in a division by 0, so I'm not sure how that would be overcome.

Proof (steps where I have doubts are marked with an "X"):

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be differentiable functions.
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[f(g(x))\right]=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{f(g(x+\Delta x))-f(g(x))}{\Delta x}$$
Now, we let $\Delta g=g(x+\Delta x)-g(x)$.
$$\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\Delta g=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}[g(x+\Delta x)-g(x)]=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}g(x+\Delta x)-\lim_{\Delta x\to0}g(x)=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}[g(x+\Delta x)]-g(x)$$
Because $g$ is continuous, we have
$$\lim_{\Delta x\to0}[g(x+\Delta x)]-g(x)=g\left(\lim_{\Delta x\to0}[x+\Delta x]\right)-g(x)=g\left(\lim_{\Delta x\to0}x+\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\Delta x\right)-g(x)
=g(x+0)-g(x)=g(x)-g(x)=0$$
Therefore, as $\Delta x\to0$, $\Delta g\to0$

$$\Delta g=\frac{g(x+\Delta x)-g(x)}{\Delta x}\cdot\Delta x$$

$$\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\Delta g=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{g(x+\Delta x)-g(x)}{\Delta x}\cdot\Delta x=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{g(x+\Delta x)-g(x)}{\Delta x}\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\Delta x=g'(x)\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\Delta x$$

We divide $g'(x)$ from both sides of the equation $\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\Delta g=g'(x)\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\Delta x$ to get
$$\frac{1}{g'(x)}\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\Delta g=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\Delta x\quad\times$$
Because $g'(x)$ is a function of $x$, it is a constant with respect to $\Delta x$, and so:
$$\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{\Delta g}{g'(x)}=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\Delta x$$
Finally, because $\Delta x\to0\implies\Delta g\to0$, we have
$$\lim_{\Delta g\to0}\Delta x=\lim_{\Delta g\to0}\frac{\Delta g}{g'(x)}\quad\times$$

$$g(x+\Delta x)=g(x)+\Delta g$$

$$\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{g(x+\Delta x)-g(x)}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta g\to0}\frac{f(g(x)+\Delta g)-f(g(x))}{\frac{\Delta g}{g'(x)}}\quad\times$$
$$=g'(x)\lim_{\Delta g\to0}\frac{f(g(x)+\Delta g)-f(g(x))}{\Delta g}=g'(x)f'(g(x))$$

Comment: This is not a "please check my proof" site. The `solution-verification` tag explicitly says: "For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so."

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I added precisely what my doubts were at the bottom of the post. Is it perhaps the title? In that case I will change that.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Alright, I moved my doubts to the top and rephrased the title, as well as shown exactly where in the proof they are.